# Append array data into a string

Tags: c#, arrays

I have written this piece of code:

```
int i = 0;
br.BaseStream.Position = i;
armorvalues[i] = br.ReadBytes(0x000E91D4);     

string[] outbyte= new string[0x000E91D4];
for (int j=0; j < 0x000E91D4; j++)
{
    outbyte[j] = Convert.ToString(String.Format("{0:X2}", armorvalues[0][j]));
}
```

Now since this is an array and I want to some algorithmic operations on the whole data, I need to convert it into a string. i need to append it in a single string. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe `string.Concat`?

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert it into a string to work with? The data you have shown doesn't look like it would benefit from such an interpretation.

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? I don't clearly understand the logics behind converting **byte array** to **string array**? What should every string in an array contain? If you need to convert byte array to a string by concatenating its hexadecimal representations, you can simply do `String.Join("", bytes.Select(b => $"{b:X2}"))`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev When you need to concatenate strings without anything between them, better use `string.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` rather than `string.Join` with an empty string

Comment: @KooKiz Yes, you are right, just a habit, thanks :) So, it will be even simpler - `string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => $"{b:X2}"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `StringBuilder` class

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(0x000E91D4*2); // length * 2 since every byte is going to be represented by 2 chars
for (int j=0; j < 0x000E91D4; j++)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(String.Format("{0:X2}", armorvalues[0][j])));
}
string yourString = sb.ToString();
```

Edit:
I was not aware of that `string.Join` overload that takes an IEnumerable, that it more elegant, go with Gilad Green's solution or if you don't want the values be separated by an empty space (" ") just do

```
string output = string.Concat(armorvalues[0].Select(item => String.Format("{0:X2}", item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do so, maybe if you explain better your need then it'll be good. But for your question:

You can use `string.Join`:

```
var strValue = string.Join(" ", outbyte);
```

And instead of doing it after the look you can also:

```
var strValue = string.Join(" ", armorvalues[0].Select(item => String.Format("{0:X2}", item)));
```